# Get rows with only one reference in many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship

I have three MySQL tables with many-to-many relationship.

One table is for tasks, another is for users, and the third is for assigning tasks to users (each task can be assigned to several users).

```
users:           tasks:            assigned:
+----+------+    +----+-------+    +---------+---------+
| id | name |    | id | title |    | task_id | user_id |
+----+------+    +----+-------+    +---------+---------+
| 1  | John |    | 1  | One   |    |    1    |    1    |
+----+------+    +----+-------+    +---------+---------+
| 2  | Mike |    | 2  | Two   |    |    1    |    2    |
+----+------+    +----+-------+    +---------+---------+
                                   |    2    |    1    |
                                   +---------+---------+
```

How do I get tasks assigned to only one user?

How do I get tasks assigned to only one particular user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all tables together. Use the following to show all tasks assigned to John:

```
SELECT name,title
FROM users
JOIN assigned ON (user_id=users.id)
JOIN tasks ON (tasks.id=task_id)
WHERE name="John";
```

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to see all tasks that were only assigned to one user.

```
SELECT title 
FROM tasks
JOIN assigned ON (task_id=id)
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

In latter you don't necessarily need to know to who tasks were assigned to, just that they were only assigned to one user. Therefore you don't need to join `users` table.

**Update:**

You can use the following to find tasks assigned to John alone:

```
SELECT name,title 
 FROM tasks
  JOIN assigned ON (task_id=tasks.id)
  JOIN users ON (user_id=users.id)
 GROUP BY tasks.id
 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 and name="John";
```

This is possible due to two reasons:

1. MySQL allows non-aggregated references in `HAVING` clause.
2. `COUNT(*)=1` forces `name` to be single value - i.e. you are not in a situation where `name` would have both 'John' and 'Mike'.

Comment: If another table will be joined (for example, table containing comments for each task), the query will work not as expected. In order for it to work as intended always, HAVING condition should evaluate COUNT from exact columns, e.g.:

`HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 1 and name="John"`

Comment: True, it'd fail same user is assigned multiple times to same task. Semantically it doesn't make much sense and it'd be worthwhile to avoid it by declaring (task_id, user_id) as unique in 'assigned' table. Of course same could happen if id isn't unique in 'users' or 'tasks' table.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it will fail simply if another table is joined and its columns selected, as they will interfere on `COUNT(*)`. It has nothing to do with non-unique user ids in `assigned`. Of course there can and will be non-unique user ids for example in table with users' comments.